# MATLAB: Combine matrices with different length but some identical entries in one column

Tags: matlab, matrix, combinations

Suppose I have measured two variables `a` and `b` with a different temporal resolution, e.g. I have a 7x2 matrix `A` (headers only for illustration):

```
time    value
t1      a1
t2      a2
t3      a3
t4      a4
t5      a5
t6      a6
t7      a7
```

and a 3x2 matrix `B`:

```
time    value
t2      b1
t4      b2
t6      b3
```

Is there an elegant way (i.e without looping `find`) to combine them in a 3x2 matrix `C` that only includes times where I have measured both `a` and `b`:

```
time    value a     value b
t2      a2          b1
t4      a4          b2
t6      a6          b3
```

?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perform set intersection:

```
[~,IA,IB]=intersect(A(:,1),B(:,1),'rows');

C=[A(IA,:) B(IB,2)];
```